# SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata Filter and Sort Issue in List View

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, filter, sorting

My managed metadata filter is working properly by itself. However, when combined with other fields, all of my data are gone.

Here are the set of combinations where my data is gone.
1. a. Managed Metadata (one filter value)
b. Dropdown (one filter value), PASS 
 
c. Dropdown (two filter values), data are gone. FAIL 
2. a. Managed Metadata (one filter value)
b. Dropdown sort. FAIL 
3. a. Dropdown sort.
b. Managed Metadata (one filter value). PASS

I am currently using SharePoint 2013, I ready the updates on SP1 but it does not include this issue. Anyone know if this is a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed and tested on SharePoint 2013 SP1 package and have some noticeable improvements (Please refer to my list).

1. Filtering is now working.
2. Sorting is now working. However, if I filter other fields other than metadata, upon sorting, all these other fields will reset. (still a bug, but already improved)
3. N/A

Just to side track a bit. The documentation in SP1 release notes is wrong in specifying the managed metadata will only show the values found in your list. It still does not work that way.

Hope this will help some people who is struggling with the same problem.